# Do Bones and custom bone shapes account for vertices/edges/ and faces?

Tags: mesh

By that I mean do bones or custom bone shapes take up vertex or mesh data?

Just a simple yes or no answer is all I want.

Comment: Custom bone shapes are linked with meshes, hence yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bone data is stored within an armature and uses data that is unique to an armature, they use points to define each end of a bone but have no vertices, edges or faces.

Custom bone shapes are mesh objects that are assigned to be the visual representation of a bone. They normally only use vertex and edge data, it is data that is kept separate from your visible models.